# Invalid object name '#Filter'

Tags: sql-server

Есть кусок mssql-процедуры. Почему то система ругается на кусок кода начиная c `Select ...`. У коллеги все работает.

```
Create Table #flt
( 
    [Type]  int not null
,   Id      int null
,   Id2     int null
,   Id3     int null
,   Id4     int null
,   Id5     int null
,   IdStr       nvarchar(3000) collate database_default null 
,   DatJoin     nvarchar(4000) collate database_default null 
)
Exec DL_Report_AddPeriod N'#flt', @bDate, @eDate 
Insert into  #flt ( [type], id,id2,id3,id4,id5,idstr )
Select [type], id,id2,id3,id4,id5,idstr
From #Filter
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: наверное не правильное наименование столбцов в таблице #Filter или её нет, так же может нужно указать полный путь к таблице.

Comment: код то выполняется? какая ошибка. Если вопрос только в том, что подчеркивает, но работает, то это не такое уж редкое явление

Comment: @teran Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Procedure Report_USER20, Line 189
Invalid object name '#Filter'.

Comment: дак не создана видимо временная таблица